# What is the output of printf("%d",scanf("ABC"));?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("%d",scanf("ABC"));
    return 0;

}
```

When I tried running it gives output as -1. Should it not give out an error ideally?

Comment: In this case `-1` does mean a error. What else did you expect? If you input `ABC` after running it, it should print `0`.

Comment: What input file are you giving the program to process?  If you give it an empty file, or `/dev/null`, or if you immediately indicate EOF at the terminal (typing `^D` or `^Z`, depending on platform), then the `-1` return indicates EOF. For anything other than an empty file, the return value should be 0 — the file might start ABC or it might not, but you'll get a matching failure if it does not, and zero conversions if it does, so the result will be 0. Neither the `printf()` nor the `scanf()` functions are required to produce any error message when misused, abused, or otherwise used erroneously.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here

```
printf("%d",scanf("ABC"));
```

`scanf()` waits for user input and if user input is other than EOF(sending EOF indication by hitting CTRL+D on linux or CTRL+Z on windows) & an empty file, it returns `zero`. and that return value gets printed by `printf()`.

As I highlighted below this `scanf("ABC")` return `0` even in the event of an early matching failure.

From the manual page of `scanf()`

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> These  functions  **return the number of input items successfully**
>   matched
>          and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or **even zero in the
>          event of an early matching failure**.
>
> The  **value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
>   either
>          the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs**.   EOF  is
>          also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
>          for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is  set  indicate  the
>          error.

*Should it not give out an error ideally?* No,read the syntax of `scanf()`, it is

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

and it's first argument is of `const char*` type i.e `scanf()` expects 1st argument as of `const char*` and 1st argument provided is `"ABC"` which is of `char*` type though you should provide some format specifier like `%s` etc.

Also as mentioned in comments neither `printf()` nor `scanf()` functions are required to produce any error message when misused, abused, or otherwise used erroneously.

Answer (score 1):

> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
>   either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
>   EOF is also returned if a read error occurs

Answer (score 0):

> What is the output of `printf("%d",scanf("ABC"));`?

Lets try some slightly more informative test:

```
int main() {
    printf("%d\n",scanf("ABC"));
    int ch =   fgetc(stdin);
    printf("%d <%c>\n",ch, ch);
}
```

With input "ABCD\n", the `scanf("ABC")` result of 0 as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched (there are no specifiers to match and so no conversions) and neither end of-file nor rare input error occurred. `"ABC"` was consumed. The next character received was `'D'`.

```
0
68 <D>
```

With input "AB\n", the `scanf("ABC")` result of 0 as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched. `"AB"` was consumed. The next character received was `'\n'`.

```
0
13 <
>
```

With input "xyz\n", the `scanf("ABC")` result of 0 as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched. Nothing was consumed. The next character received was `'x'`.

```
xyz
0
120 <x>
```

With input "Ayz\n", the `scanf("ABC")` result of 0 as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched. `"A"` was consumed. The next character received was `'y'`.

```
Ayz
0
121 <y>
```

With input "ABC" and then end-of-file signaled, the `scanf("ABC")` result of -1 (`EOF` on my machine) as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched and end-of-file was detected. `"ABC"` was consumed. The next character received was not a character but the `EOF` from `fgetc()`.

```
ABC-1
-1 <�>
```

With no inpit and then end-of-file immediate signaled, the `scanf("ABC")` result of -1 (`EOF` on my machine) as expected as 0 input specifiers were matched and end-of-file was detected. Nothing was consumed. The next character received was not a character but the `EOF` from `fgetc()`.

```
-1
-1 <�>
```

> When I tried running it gives output as -1. Should it not give out an error ideally?

No as there is no *error* and C does not generally give out error messages.

Depending on input, a result of 0 or the -1 (or whatever the negative value of `EOF` on your machine) is expected.  There can be input matching failures and the results seen above.

---

With `scanf("ABC")`, input is consumed if it matches, first `'A'`, then `'B'`, etc.  Note that `"A"` and the rest are not `*scanf()` *specifiers* like `"%d"`.  If end-of-file did not occur (or rare input error - broken keyboard cable, etc.), 0 is returned, else `EOF`.

> The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.  C11dr §7.21.6.2 16

Well then what is an *input failure*?

> If the length of the input item is zero, the execution of the directive fails; this condition is a matching failure unless end-of-file, an encoding error, or a read error prevented input from the stream, in which case it is an input failure.   §7.21.6.2 9